# Any mathematical significance?

Tags: calculus

Let $y = f(x)$ be some function, with the second and third derivatives of $f(x)$ in the neighborhood of some point $c$:

$d^{(2)} = \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}$

$d^{(3)} = \frac{d^3 f}{dx^3}$

Define quantity $Q$:

$Q(c) = -f(c)\frac{d^{(3)}} {d^{(2)}}$

In economics, if $f(x)$ is a utility function, then quantity $Q$ is known as the "relative prudence". Is $Q$ known to have any significance mathematically? That is, if you are not an economist, would the formulation of $Q$ ring any bells in your head which would associate $Q$ with some mathematical concept or term?

Comment: Well the third derivative can be seen as a speed of how fast the convexity of a function changes. That is the origin of the prudence. I dont see any meaning for this formula if we dont link it to a convexity some how.